# Where does "pod install" analyze and download dependencies and their versions?

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods

Upon issuing pod install I am told dependencies are being analyzed and downloaded.
[with this output as the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgcw4.png)

My question is what is being analyzed for dependencies, where did that list in green come from, and how are the version numbers for elements of the list in green selected? I played with podfile platform iOS version numbers to see if the ones in green would change. They did not.

My problem is geolocator_apple (1.2.0) in my pod is actually at 2.3.2. Flutter pub upgrade shows geolocator_apple to be at 2.3.2.  I assume the two have two match though? Or am I being politely told that I have to stay at 1.2.0? Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Could you share your Podfile and PodFile.lock? We don't know which version you specified (which rule?) and also the pod might be a dependency of another one that works only with version 1.2.0 and not 2.3.2 explaining why it's stuck on that version. But it's hard to tell...

Comment: please add all required details as text to your question